# Non-nullable instance field '_controller' must be initialized

Tags: flutter

- The method 'TapBar' isn't defined for the type '_HomescreenState'.
- Non-nullable instance field '_controller' must be initialized.

I'm getting above errors in my code.. how to correct those. appreciate your help on this..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Homescreen extends StatefulWidget {
  Homescreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _HomescreenState createState() => _HomescreenState();
}

class _HomescreenState extends State<Homescreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

   TabController _controller;   //error

@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  _controller =TabController(length: 4, vsync:this, initialIndex: 0);
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Whatsapp Clone"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), onPressed: () {}),
    ],
        bottom: TapBar(                //error
          _controller:_controller,
        ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider changing `TapBar` to `TabBar` for a start, and you could look at the answers below to fix the next issue.

Comment: you can use this doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html, use late in initializing _controller .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of null safety your variable must be initialzied when created, to fix this you can use late to tell it that it will be initialized after being created but before being used:

```
late final TabController _controller;
```

Answer (score 2):

Call Like this :

```
late final TabController _controller;

void initState(){
 
  _controller =TabController(length: 4, vsync:this, initialIndex: 0);
 super.initState();
}
```

Call the `super.initState();` after _controller initialization

Comment: I thought all added code should come after the super.initState();
No ?